# Can't import online zfs pools (zfsonlinux)

Tags: fedora, zfs

I am running a home NAS alongside my desktop (I'm dual booting windows and Fedora 29) and for some reason, I couldn't import my zpools today.
I'm trying to access via Fedora 29 or a Ubuntu Server 18.04 VM, and both put out exactly the same error - Cant import [pool name]: I/O Error
I've two pools on a single disk each, and both show the same errors, which leads me to believe something is wrong in the software level.
Both disks seem OK (one is rather new) and have shown no signs of failure.
This issue first started after initially importing the pools on Fedora (which worked OK until rebooting).
zdb -C -e shows the following:
pool 1: (a 3TB WD Red drive)

```
MOS Configuration:
        version: 5000
        name: 'Big-Red'
        state: 0
        txg: 33140
        pool_guid: 2470736168679644355
        errata: 0
        hostname: 'zfscloud'
        com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
        vdev_children: 1
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 2470736168679644355
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 5103424011777975964
                path: '/dev/sdb1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 256
                metaslab_shift: 34
                ashift: 12
                asize: 3000578342912
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 129
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 130
                degraded: 1
                aux_state: 'err_exceeded'
        features_for_read:
            com.delphix:hole_birth
            com.delphix:embedded_data
```

pool 2 (a 750GB WD Blue drive):

```
MOS Configuration:
        version: 5000
        name: 'Trunk'
        state: 0
        txg: 22372
        pool_guid: 14763288275454781571
        errata: 0
        hostname: 'zfscloud'
        com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
        vdev_children: 1
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 14763288275454781571
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 9605113579753698417
                path: '/dev/sdc1'
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 131
                metaslab_shift: 32
                ashift: 9
                asize: 750141308928
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 129
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 130
                degraded: 1
                aux_state: 'err_exceeded'
        features_for_read:
            com.delphix:hole_birth
            com.delphix:embedded_data
```

The strange part is both pools are shown as online:

```
pool: Trunk
     id: 14763288275454781571
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

        Trunk       ONLINE
          sdc       ONLINE

   pool: Big-Red
     id: 2470736168679644355
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

        Big-Red     ONLINE
          sdb       ONLINE
```